# ¿Es Posible Llamar Un Método Desde Un IntentService?

Tags: android

Me he encontrado con un problema al adentrarme en el mundo de los servicios en android. Al tratar de llamar un método que se encuentra en otra clase desde mi IntentService me ocurrió el típico error la aplicación no responde. Si notan un error en mi código o saben si es posible o no llamar a los métodos desde un IntentService por favor comunicármelo. Gracias.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
           JAVA ja=new JAVA();
           ja.file("vamos");


        }
    });
}
```

Coloco solamente el método onHandleIntent porque es donde se ejecuta todo mi código del servicio de prueba que intente. Gracias

Comment: Cuando dices _llamar a un método_, te refieres a `mHandler`? Es mHandler miembro de la clase? Que hace tu clase JAVA?

Comment: No puedo ayudarte con tu bloqueo sin más información, pero te comento que puedes hacer referencia a cualquier variable miembro de tu clase y llamar a sus métodos (como adivino que es `mHandler`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible, considera un llamado a una clase que extiende de `IntentService`:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class));
```

Tu clase que extiende  `IntentService` contiene un método de ejecución llamado `onHandleIntent()`, dentro de este método puedes llamar tu método:

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {           

    public MyIntentService(){
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        //Llamar método!
        myMetodo();

    }
}
```